# Know of any setup tutorials for SQL Server Express and C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm a C# and MySQL developer, but I'm looking into Microsoft's SQL Server for a new project.

I'm familiar with MySQL syntax and the .NET connector.  Does anyone know of any decent tutorials that just cover the code to interact with SQL Server? No C# basics or SQL basics, just how to get the two technologies to connect and interact.

Comment: There is no "single" code here; however, if you start with reading MSDN on SqlConnection, and then also look at technologies like EF, NHibernate, or tools like "dapper", "simple.data", etc...

Comment: Yeah, reading the links posted below, I'm thinking this may not be the product for me... Is there no simple API to just connect, send queries, and receive data arrays back?  Everything seems too wrapped already... I'll look into SqlConnection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4416/Beginners-guide-to-accessing-SQL-Server-through-C) is a basic tutorial to

- 1 open a connection to sql server
- 2 select data from the db
- 3 display    the data

This implementation of a connection will work with the .NET frameworks (specifically ASP and ADO)